# I cannot eject my hdd which I just got and there is nothing on it

Tags: mount, hard-drive

Just plugged in my new hdd (Intenso 2,5 Memory case with 1 TB) and can't seem to eject it.

I looked for the name of the hdd in the 'Disks' App and it was sdc (`/dev/sdc`).

Tried: `sudo eject /dev/sdc`

Result: `unable to eject`

Tried: `sudo umount dev/sdc`

Result: `no mount point specified`

Installed `pydf` and ran it:

```
/dev/sdb2    23G  15G 6406M  67.3 [###.] /                               
/dev/sda1   396M  31M  365M   7.7 [....] /boot/efi                       
/dev/loop0  128k 128k     0 100.0 [####] /snap/bare/5                    
/dev/loop1   56M  56M     0 100.0 [####] /snap/core18/2409               
/dev/loop2   62M  62M     0 100.0 [####] /snap/core20/1405               
/dev/loop4   62M  62M     0 100.0 [####] /snap/core20/1518               
/dev/loop3  156M 156M     0 100.0 [####] /snap/firefox/1232              
/dev/loop5  162M 162M     0 100.0 [####] /snap/firefox/1498              
/dev/loop6  401M 401M     0 100.0 [####] /snap/gnome-3-38-2004/112       
/dev/loop7  249M 249M     0 100.0 [####] /snap/gnome-3-38-2004/99        
/dev/loop8   81M  81M     0 100.0 [####] /snap/gtk-common-themes/1534    
/dev/loop9   92M  92M     0 100.0 [####] /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535    
/dev/loop10 566M 566M     0 100.0 [####] /snap/pycharm-community/286     
/dev/loop11  46M  46M     0 100.0 [####] /snap/snap-store/575            
/dev/loop14 384k 384k     0 100.0 [####] /snap/snapd-desk~-integration/10
/dev/loop15 384k 384k     0 100.0 [####] /snap/snapd-desk~-integration/14
/dev/loop12  44M  44M     0 100.0 [####] /snap/snapd/15177               
/dev/loop13  47M  47M     0 100.0 [####] /snap/snapd/16010
```

When I tried the `sudo umount /dev/sdc` again it said `not mounted`.

The command `lsblk` resulted in:

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
loop0    7:0    0     4K  1 loop /snap/bare/5
loop1    7:1    0  55,5M  1 loop /snap/core18/2409
loop2    7:2    0  61,9M  1 loop /snap/core20/1405
loop3    7:3    0 155,6M  1 loop /snap/firefox/1232
loop4    7:4    0  61,9M  1 loop /snap/core20/1518
loop5    7:5    0 161,5M  1 loop /snap/firefox/1498
loop6    7:6    0 400,8M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-38-2004/112
loop7    7:7    0 248,8M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-38-2004/99
loop8    7:8    0  81,3M  1 loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/1534
loop9    7:9    0  91,7M  1 loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535
loop10   7:10   0 565,5M  1 loop /snap/pycharm-community/286
loop11   7:11   0  45,9M  1 loop /snap/snap-store/575
loop12   7:12   0  43,6M  1 loop /snap/snapd/15177
loop13   7:13   0    47M  1 loop /snap/snapd/16010
loop14   7:14   0   284K  1 loop /snap/snapd-desktop-integration/10
loop15   7:15   0   284K  1 loop /snap/snapd-desktop-integration/14
sda      8:0    0 232,9G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   400M  0 part /boot/efi
├─sda2   8:2    0    16M  0 part 
├─sda3   8:3    0   232G  0 part 
└─sda4   8:4    0   500M  0 part 
sdb      8:16   0   1,8T  0 disk 
├─sdb1   8:17   0   1,8T  0 part 
├─sdb2   8:18   0  23,3G  0 part /
└─sdb3   8:19   0     6G  0 part [SWAP]
sdc      8:32   0 931,5G  0 disk 
└─sdc1   8:33   0 931,5G  0 part 
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

`sudo eject f- /dev/sdc` also just lead to
`unable to eject`.

And finally, `type -a eject` printed:

```
type -a eject
eject is /usr/bin/eject
eject is /bin/eject
```

I checked that the eject command is really installed with: `apt list --installed eject` and it showed that it was installed.

I literally checked everything on like 4 websites even if the problem was even slightly close to mine but apparently nothing worked so far.

I would appreciate it so much if anyone would be willing to help.

Thank you,

Comment: If the drive isn't mounted then it makes no sense to eject it. That is exactly what the error messages are telling you.

Comment: You unmount (`umount`) hard drives.  You `eject` CD-ROM/DVD/Blu-Ray drives.

Comment: I was used to always needing to eject everything from windows

So that implies that the post is useless and I could just go ahead and delete it?

Comment: Well, other newcomers might have similar questions, so you need not delete the question. - And it is still very **important to unmount the drive** before turning it off or removing it. Unmounting will force buffered data to be written to the drive.

Comment: what Windows calls "eject" for regular drives is just unmounting it